# How to create groups without creating sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

I can't find the conventional group settings in SharePoint Online. For some reason I got the impression that everything would be controlled from the admin center, (probably because there's a big button called Groups in the admin menu under Users) but it's still the same for Groups. So that's cool.

I can't delete this question, but I would.

I also can't vote on it, but I would vote -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, you're working with SharePoint online, not 2016. 2016 refers to the on-prem version of SharePoint.

The word Group can refer to a couple different things:

Office 365 Group - A group of users that exists in Azure AD that also gets a team site, distribution list email address, and other features.

SharePoint Group - A group used to work with permissions within a SharePoint site collection.

SharePoint Groups in online are equivalent to SharePoint groups in SharePoint 2013, 2010, etc. To create a SP group, go to a site --> site setting --> people and groups.

But you may want to read up further on SP online first, as the old way of doing things was to create a site collection with a bunch of subsites, which is where custom SP groups really helped out. The new advice is to create a flat structure: lots of site collections without subsites. In this new model, custom SP groups aren't as helpful, as an SP Group is only available within a single site collection.

Comment: SP groups are unchanged, and work the same as in 2013.

Comment: SharePoint groups are managed from within the site collection, as in 2010/2013/2016. Not the admin center. Navigate to a SharePoint site, and go to the gear icon --> site settings.